# programmatically send outlook email from shared mailbox

Tags: python, windows, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to send an email with python from a shared mailbox.

I have been able to sucessfuly send it through my own email, but sending one with a shared mailbox (that I have tested that I have access too) is giving me issues.

Code used for email script in python

```
import win32com.client
import win32com
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Python Email Test"
newMail.Body = "Test"
newMail.To = 'hi@hi.com'
newMail.Send()
```

I know that below is how I can read my emails from a shared Folder.
    
    `outlook = win32com.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    dir_accounts = outlook.Folders("SharedFolder")`

Any ideas on how to combine these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case if you have multiple accounts configured in Outlook you may use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class. Or if you have sufficient privileges (rights) you may consider using the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145.aspx) property which is a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

Answer (score 4):

Added this right before the `newMail.send()` step and it worked

```
newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'SharedFolder'
```