# Send email from mailbox in Python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

currently I am using the win32com.client way of sending emails via Python 3, as I do not have access to SMTP. My code is below for reference:

```
def send_email(recipient, content, cc):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = content[0]
    mail.HTMLBody = content[1]
    mail.CC = cc
    mail.Send()
```

My question is, is there a way to send an email using this method but send it 'from' another mailbox from within my outlook. For example, I have my email "name@domain.com" and a mailbox called "application@domain.com", which I have send as rights on. Is there a way to change it so that it'll send from the "application@domain.com" email? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to find the solution! If anybody else needs it, use the property:
`newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'SharedFolder'`

Thanks to [programmatically send outlook email from shared mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876817/programmatically-send-outlook-email-from-shared-mailbox)